# Forming national-agreement government in Nepal?

Tags: government, parties, nationalism

Nepal is one of the developing Himalaya countries **[with Mt. Everest]** in south Asia in between India and China. For about 10 years, there was an armed civil war led by NCP(Maoist). After peace talk between the Maoists and the government, Nepal has now become the Republic country and integration of two armies is in the process since 4 years.

About four years ago [April 10, 2008], an election for constitution assembly had completed but the CA failed to write the constitution & the house is dissolved in May 28, 2012.

Currently, the government is led by Maoist and the government was formed on the basis of majority before the house was dissolved. Two major parties NC & NCP(UML) are in the opposition demanding for national-agreement government with presence of most of the political parties.

But, the government and its parties are saying agreement-in-package regarding to the constitution, election-government & next CA election proposed to be held on May by the Gov. The opposition parties say it as the nonsense thing to puzzle them.

So, My Question is:

**How the Nepalese political parties can form the so called national-agreement government and Nepalese people can get their constitution as soon as possible?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It was asked before the question that you've provided in above link...so how can it be duplicate? Rather the question in the link should be marked as duplicate...I think @Yannis